# Outlook Client and DKIM

Tags: email

We have our domain email setup with SPF and DKIM - both which seem to be operating normally. When sending emails from webmail, DKIM (and SPF) are working correctly. We have some users using Outlook as an email client. When sending emails via Outlook it seems there is no DKIM or SPF "signature" in the emails. We've confirmed that all of the settings are correct for the server information in the account in Outlook.

Thank you

Comment: I can't find a question in there.

Answer (score 2):

When the SPF is not validating, its clear that the mail are not going through your servers. Propably the end user has configured their client to mail through a ISP-owned "smarthost" that the ISP enforces.

Double check the client configuration and firewall settings, and ensure the mails are really reaching your relay SMTP.